# Postgres, earthdistance - sort results by gps distance

Tags: sql, postgresql, gps, distance, earthdistance

Currently I have a query that selects all the objects closer than X km from specified GPS coordinations:

```
$query = 
  'SELECT * FROM t_activity WHERE
   POINT(gps_lat||\',\'||gps_lon) <@> 
   POINT(
     '.$gps_latitude.', 
     '.$gps_longitude.'
   ) <= '.$search_range;
```

Im not skilled in DBs at all, but I would like to know:

Is it also possible to modify the query in order to sort it from closest to farest results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your query I assume it should be

```
$query = 
  'SELECT * FROM t_activity WHERE
   POINT(gps_lat||\',\'||gps_lon) <@> 
   POINT(
     '.$gps_latitude.', 
     '.$gps_longitude.'
   ) <= '.$search_range.'
   ORDER BY POINT(gps_lat||\',\'||gps_lon) <@> 
   POINT(
     '.$gps_latitude.', 
     '.$gps_longitude.'
   )
';
```